# Why is the photo quality terrible in Automator?

Tags: automator

I am trying to use Automator as a Photo Booth but when I use the `video snapshot` command the photo quality is terrible. The built in camera is fine in other apps such as Skype or Photo Booth? I can't find anything online about this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but it seems to save the image as a 201x201 pixel tiff file.

You could also install `imagesnap` with `brew install imagesnap` and then use something like `/usr/local/bin/imagesnap ~/Desktop/$(date +%y%m%d%H%M%S).png` in a Run Shell Script action.